# How to prepare a list containing a mix of integers, float and strings using lambda function?

Tags: python, list, lambda, type-conversion, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert:

```
data = 'A|B|2|D|0.3|5|kg|1.69|m'

to list
['A','B',2,'D',0.3,5,'kg',1.69,'m'] 
# where every element is the type it should be (not all are strings)
```

I tried:

```
data_list = da.split('|')
print(da_list)
['A', 'B', '2', 'D', '0.3', '5', 'kg', '1.69', 'm'] # every element is string

#Then

data_list02 = map(lambda x: (int(x) or float(x)) if x.isdigit() else str(x), data_list)
print (data_list02)
['A', 'B', 2, 'D', '0.3', 5, 'kg', '1.69', 'm'] # float are retained as str
```

What is wrong with the lambda solution I tried? I am not trying to write another `def function`

Comment: *the type it should be* doesn't sound very nice. And `0.3` is not a digit

Comment: for starters, `'0.3'.isdigit() == False`, thus no `float` conversion will happen...

Comment: Hmmm. That's enlightening. How do I solve this? any idea?

Comment: You could try to use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Why are people downvoting my question? Is it a bad question.

Comment: @everestial007, how about the numbers in scientific notation, like `1.00e-05` ? How should they be treated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `literal_eval` from `ast` module with a custom method like this example:

```
from ast import literal_eval as le

def format(data, sep= '|'):
    for k in data.split(sep):
        try:
            yield le(k)
        # Or:
        # You can escape any kind of odd data by using:
        # except Exception:
        #     yield k
        # Or list them then yield k
        except ValueError:
            yield k
        # Thanks to @RomanPerekhrest's comment
        except SyntaxError:
            yield k

data = 'A|B|2|D|0.3|5|kg|1.69|m'
final = list(format(data))
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 2, 'D', 0.3, 5, 'kg', 1.69, 'm']
```

**PS:** I didn't test this method within a large number of data, leave your feedbacks if it fails with any.

Comment: `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000000036450B8>`

Comment: With what kind of data ? With my `'A|B|2|D|0.3|5|kg|1.69|m'` it works well. Can you tell me with wich kind of data it fails ?

Comment: `data = 'A|B|2|D|0.3|5|kg|1.69|m'
data_list = list(map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x), data.split('|')))`

Comment: Look at my answer, i'm using `try ... except` block to escape this `ValueError` exception. Please run the example in my answer.

Comment: try to process this sequence `data = 'A|B|2|D|0.3|5|kg|1.69|m|*10e'`. What do you see?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks. This is a kind of odd data. I'll updata my answer now.

Comment: @Look now, you can escape those odd data and return them as a string. `literal_eval` is'nt a glod bullet, but i can help with some kind of data.

Comment: ok, the next moment is numbers in scientific notation like `10e+3`, which will be converted to `10000.0` by your approach. I don't know if the OP ready for such conversion. It should be elaborated

Comment: Really, i don't know if there is a general solution to this kind of question. `eval` is bad and shouldn't be used because it represent a hole of security. `literal_eval` is much more secure but it cannot give a good representation for any kind of data. With the OP input data, `literal_eval` can do the trick however, the OP need to elaborate more this solution in order to escape a malformed output.

Comment: I have asked the question. Let's see what will the OP respond

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
data_List=[int(x) if x.isdigit() else float(x) if x.replace(".", "", 1).isdigit() else str(x) for x in data]
```

Example :

```
>>> data = 'A|B|2|D|0.3|5|kg|1.69|m'
>>> data=data.split('|')
>>> data
['A', 'B', '2', 'D', '0.3', '5', 'kg', '1.69', 'm']
>>> data_List=[int(x) if x.isdigit() else float(x) if x.replace(".", "", 1).isdigit() else str(x) for x in data]
>>> data_List
['A', 'B', 2, 'D', 0.3, 5, 'kg', 1.69, 'm']
```

***EDIT***

If you have negative integer or float use :

```
data_List=[int(x) if x.lstrip('-').isdigit() else float(x) if x.lstrip('-').replace(".", "", 1).isdigit() else str(x) for x in data]
```

Example :

```
>>> data = 'A|B|2|D|0.3|-5|kg|-1.69|m'
>>> data=data.split('|')
>>> data_List=[int(x) if x.lstrip('-').isdigit() else float(x) if x.lstrip('-').replace(".", "", 1).isdigit() else str(x) for x in data]
>>> data_list
['A', 'B', 2, 'D', 0.3, -5, 'kg', -1.69, 'm']
```

Comment: Hmm, why doesn't it convert `-5` to `int` and `-1.0` to `float`?